# Can't Display a message for a validation using jsf

Tags: validation, jsf

I'm new to web development using JSF , i have an issue in displaying a message for a validation.
I'm trying to display a message related to length validation.

this is the code for the page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:message showDetail="true" showSummary="true" for="txtNum" />

        <p:panelGrid columns="2">

            <p:outputLabel value="value" id="lblValue" for="txtNum" />
            <p:inputText value="#{test.num}" required="true" id="txtNum">
                <f:facet name="">
                    <f:validateLength maximum="3"></f:validateLength>
                </f:facet>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:commandButton value="do" action="#{test.func()}"></p:commandButton>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

this the code for the managed bean (configured from faces config):

```
public class Test {
    private int num;

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String func()
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Don't forget about IDs and naming containers.When using AJAX do not skip `process` and `update` attributes.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="formGrid">
        <p:outputLabel value="value" id="lblValue" for=":form:txtNum" />
        <p:inputText value="#{test.num}" required="true" id="txtNum">
            <f:validateLength maximum="3"/>
        </p:inputText>
        <h:message showDetail="true" showSummary="true" for=":form:txtNum" />
        <p:commandButton value="do" action="#{test.func()}" process=":form:formGrid" update=":form:formGrid"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```